# Memory Fragmentation and Garbage Collection in network server apps

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

Actually i developed an tcp based network server that does a lot of read an write and uses less than zero cpu for its business logic, it acts as bridge between two endpoint.
The network server is developed for .NET 4.5, it uses:

- IOCP (Socket.xxxAsync)
- a Buffer Pool of preallocated SocketAsyncEventArgs (used for SendAsync and ReadAsync)
- a Buffer Pool of preallocated byte[] (used only for read)
- System.Collections.Concurrent
- Less than zero locks (well, actually there is one :))
- some other stuff

My concerns are related to the garbage collection, infact, as far i understand, while i avoid the memory fragmentation preallocating all the buffers i need, the garbage collector check if them must be collected or not because they aren't allocated inside the large heap.

Would be better, instead to allocate 10.000 byte[8192] would be better allocate a big byte[81920000] and use ArraySegment to use slices?

Thank you.

### UPDATE

I switched to server mode garbage collection and it seems that my system works better than before (actually i'm able to handle up to 4GiB of traffic with 5000 clients on the same machine, this means 10000 sockets).
I'll start to test the architecture on more machine in short.

Comment: Fragmentation is only an issue on the LOH. Just keep it simple and don't solve problems you don't have. I'm not even sure the pre-allocation is such a good idea.

Comment: @HenkHolterman my point is exactly this: if i've many small object, the GC will do a lot of work when it needs to decide how to "compress" the heap ... if i have a big object in the large heap i'll avoid this but i don't know if this can be really useful or not

Comment: It's only a burden for the GC when memory reaches a certain age. Gen 0 allocations are very cheap to deallocate. Whatever you do, measure it. Your inuition will let you down.

Comment: If you use `ArraySegment`, the GC has to examine all those structures looking for references, so it's unlikely that you'd really gain anything. Going to the server GC was a smart move. By the way, can you please explain what kind of quantum computer you're using to get a program use "less than zero CPU"?

Comment: Actually, the main work of the server is to check and forward requests between a browser and a set of mobile devices ... and the deveopment machine is quite big :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with how you break down data for sending and receiving. When receiving data try to keep any buffers below the minimum for the LOH, i.e. <80Kb. Same for sending.

An alternative is to create a pool of buffers of a fixed size to use and recycle as necessary. This avoid the constant creation and destruction of allocation avoiding any memory fragmentation issues.

The final choice, as with most problems, depends on what's optimum for your final solution. It can be easier to avoid fragmentation by just using small buffers but this can also have an associated performance cost.

Comment: This is what i, actually, do: i have N fixed byte[] that i use as buffers that are created in chunks as i explained in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I had this "memory leak"-like problem when I was developing a high performance TCP server based on `SocketAsyncEventArgs`.

The problem is when you use a buffer (`byte[]`) **it gets pinned**. So actually GC can not do anything about it.

Personally I wrote this class (not exactly this):

```
class Buffer
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;

    public Buffer()
    {
        InUse = false;
        Bytes = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    }

    public bool InUse { get; set; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; private set; }
}
```

And another class named `BufferPool` which has `List<Buffer>` as a pool of buffers (the logic for detecting dead connections and free their pool and etc is very complicated in my case so I skip the internals).

That way you can reuse the allocated byte array as a buffer for a new action.

I have implemented it this way because I could not restrict the max number of connections. If you can restrict the number of connections to a specific max then [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod) can help.

Note: I forgot to say there is no way to reclaim the allocated memory in this case.

Comment: I do something really close to what you do: i have BufferPool<T>, to handle buffer pool of different types, not only byte, and a ByteBuffer, that holds the byte[]. When a client connects i do a BufferPool.CheckOut and when the client disconnect i do a BufferPool.CheckIn and this works like a charm.

Comment: Do you hold the reference to that byte[] to be reused? That's the key.

Comment: Well, the BufferPool holds a reference to ByteBuffer object (that contains the byte[]) while the buffer is in the queue but when it is checked out, there reference is being holded by a reference tied to the connection (and, consequently, the byte[] is assigned to the SocketAsyncEventArgs) until the connection ends and the buffer is checked in the buffer pool again ... but this is the point of my question and, by the way, actually i pre-allocated the SocketAsyncEventArgs like i did for byte[] otherwise will be there a lot of memory fragmentation in any case.

Comment: When your byte[] goes back into buffer pool then you can reuse it. That's the way it should be and you are doing the right thing. About fragmentation; in my case I had to bear it because I had no control over number of connections. But in the article that I'd referred to (on codeproject) you see that a single big byte array is allocated; then segments of it is used as buffer for SocketAsyncEventArgs. This way the fragmentation will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Client-server application in simple case means *N* clients and *1* server. Each of the client requests shall be self-contained and independent from other clients' requests. This allows you to use *N* thread to support *N* concurrent users.

Now, it is essential that threads don't use shared resources. They could, but it comes as a performance hit. Even if you use optimistic (lockless) concurrency model, this doesn't mean  threads won't compete for the shared resource.

Now if you have a separate buffer per thread, each thread uses it's own memory and no competition exist between different concurrent threads. If you have many users, this will increase memory fragmentation and CPU time spent by GC.

If you use a large, but shared buffer, you will increase time spent on trying to get access to the shared buffer for different threads. And also you will decrease time spent by GC doing collection stuff.

---

Personally, I would just use 1 small buffer per thread. This has bonuses:

- Simple model
- Less code to write, no synchronization needed
- Your CPU level is small so no need to do performance optimization
- This model is much easier to scale horizontally: add another server and a load balancer. It's working out of the box.

Comment: My TcpClient (not the .net one) class has an UserData generic object that i use to associate the data related to the TcpClient, and this works fine. However i need to track connected clients and this means shared resources, i can't avoid it, but it's not a problem. If i use a BIG byte[] i don't have the shared resource problem because to the SocketAsyncEventArgs i can assign a splice of a byte[] so i don't need to worry. My point is: could this be useful to speedup the GC and, so, to reduce slowdown during the GC execution in my application?

Comment: Alright, point taken. With BIG byte[] you would still need to keep the array slices in sync. So when a client disconnects, you can zero memory and reuse it. It might be a big hassle. Generally I like the idea of a big array and having slices per thread. Still I believe it's an over-engineering and super-fine tuning. I would not dare to do it, unless forced by realistic and harmful performance hits. Even then, you would just scale up, you can do only small performance improvement (but lots of pain fixing bugs). I would go for a simple solution that scales well by adding more servers.

Comment: I don't need to zero memory the buffer when i check in it in the bufferpool on client disconnection, it would be sufficient to use offset zero on the first read/write so any content will be overwritten. But in the end, i would need a structure that it should dispatch all the buffers on client connection and disconnection that would need a more fine grained control that the which one i'm using right now (i'm using a ConcurrentQueue). In the end, and as you suggest, this may be an over-engineering so I'll not change anything, may be in the next release. Thank you